# rosserial: cstring: No such file or directory (arduino ide)

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to make rosserial work for days now to no avail. This is the most recent issue off a fresh arduino install with a successful catkin_make and catkin_make install. I am running ubuntu 20.04. This happens when I try to verify the code in IDE

Arduino: 1.8.15 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"

```
In file included from /home/ubuntu/Desktop/arduino library/sketchbook/libraries/Rosserial_Arduino_Library/src/std_msgs/Time.h:7:0,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Desktop/arduino library/sketchbook/libraries/Rosserial_Arduino_Library/src/ros/node_handle.h:40,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Desktop/arduino library/sketchbook/libraries/Rosserial_Arduino_Library/src/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/ubuntu/Desktop/arduino library/sketchbook/Hello_world/Hello_world.ino:9:
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/arduino library/sketchbook/libraries/Rosserial_Arduino_Library/src/ros/msg.h:40:10: fatal error: cstring: No such file or directory
 #include <cstring>
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.


This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385029/rosserial:-cstring:-no-such-file-or-directory-(arduino-ide)/) by [matthewfwork](https://answers.ros.org/users/77959/matthewfwork/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to be a known issue: [ros-drivers/rosserial#518](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/518) and apparently [ros-drivers/rosserial#525](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/525) should fix it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matthewfwork](https://answers.ros.org/users/77959/matthewfwork/) on 2021-08-24**:
Sweet that seemed to have worked because now I get a new error when compliling

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"
Hello_world:2:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'Publisher'
  * rosserial Publisher Example
              ^~~~~~~~~
exit status 1
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'Publisher'
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-24**:
That would be a different problem.

**Comment by [matthewfwork](https://answers.ros.org/users/77959/matthewfwork/) on 2021-08-24**:
got it thanks for the help for original issue!